# Enlarge textarea onClick

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can anyone please let me how to Enlarge textarea while using OnClick function  or how to increase the rows on onClick?

regards
balkar

Answer (score 6):

If you can set pixel or column sizes (instead of using the `rows` and `cols` attributes), you can use the [`:focus` CSS pseudo-class](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp):

HTML:

```
<textarea id="myarea"></textarea>
```

CSS:

```
textarea#myarea { width: 100px; height: 20px; }
textarea#myarea:focus { width: 500px; height: 200px; }
```

depending on the layout, it's sometimes attractive to give the focused textarea `position: absolute` so it floats above the other elements in its enlarged state.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna use onClick, add an onClick Handler via JavaScript:

```
<html>  
    <body onLoad="load();">   
        <textarea id="t1">foo</textarea>
        <script>
        function load(){
            document.getElementById("t1").addEventListener("click",function(){ 
                this.setAttribute("rows","50"); 
            },false);  
        }  
        </script> 
    </body>
 </html>
```